# I think I lost my MAC HD (despered)

Tags: mac, format, reset, ios

So, one of these days I decided to install Ubuntu on my mac mini but not with dual boot. I just installed in mac HD. So, today I wanted back my OS system and I tried to format the HD ( from terminal ) than i would had a computer with no operational system and automatically the mac will ask me if i wanted to download the OS again. What happened was that now wen i turn on my mac it doesn't work anymore  ( doesn't open Ubuntu and don't show boot options ). All that happens is showing  a black screen with that terminal underscore "__"

Comment: [How to remove Ubuntu Linux of a Macbook and put OS X back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524462/how-to-remove-ubuntu-linux-of-a-macbook-and-put-os-x-back-on)

Answer (score 1):

Because the boot loader was wiped out with your clean Linux install, it doesn't know how to go get a fresh version of the MacOS.  Try this KB article for a clean Mac install:

http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/18/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/

You're going to put the OS on a USB drive, then hold down command during boot, should let you boot the MacOS Install off the USB Drive.  This is the same procedure that you follow when installing after replacing a hard drive  (some newer macs don't need this, and you can just hold down the command button during boot, but anything more than a couple years old does).  If you can't get access to the web to make a boot USB you can stop by an Apple Store, the help desk will drop a clean install of the OS on the computer for you (I don't think they charge for this, but don't quote me on that, they might charge your $20 or so for the OS if you want the latest version.

Best of luck.

Comment: tks a lot mate.